# world state persistence in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In hyperledger fabric **World State is the collection of variables containing the results of executed transactions** . Is the world state persisted somewhere in disk or it will be in primary memory?

What if the peer was restarted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The world state is persisted to disk in each peer at `/var/hyperledger/production`. The hyperledger fabric makes use of Rocksdb as a persistent key value store to store/retrieve the world state. So even if the peer goes down, and is brought back up the world state will still be intact.

Comment: Thanks Mate, I will have a look on that.

Comment: As of Hyperledger Fabric 1.0.0, the ledger is stored per-channel, and we support pluggable databases, with LevelDB the default (RocksDB no longer used) and CouchDB as an option.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Fabric 1.3 supports Couchdb. LevelDB is used as a default database.Your world state will be persisted in disk.You can use check the updated documentation [Couchdb in Hyperledger Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/whatsnew.html)

Comment: correction: Couchdb was supported since version 1.0. In version 1.3, querying couchdb with pagination was added